# Odoo payment flow

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I want to build a custom payment acquirer module in odoo 13 , The idea is whenever the customer click on pay , a redirect url is generated from the backend for that particular invoice then I redirect the user to that url , when payment complete the acquirer site then send a GET request to my website , in that get request I have the orderID then I can verify or not if transaction is complete . Through many research and inspection of odoo module like paypal , nelo ect... I wasn't able to create it so Im wondering what is supposed to be done
this is the code of What I started https://github.com/mama00/moncash_odoo

Comment: While showing a link to your GitHub code is OK, you should also include short example of the code that causes you the problem.

Comment: Actually I dont even know where the problem is. Im not sure I understand well what need to be done